# Wordpress WP Paging (plugin) pagination links not working....?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Good morning...

I have created a custom post type called Testimonials. To display them, I created a custom
page.php template using the following code:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
?>    
<?php
query_posts(array(                      
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'post_type' => 'testimonials',
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'paged' => $paged
)
); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="quote">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array($image_width,$image_height)); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<p><?php wp_paging(); ?></p>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The `<p><?php wp_paging(); ?></p>` is how I implement the plugin directly into the template file. I don't understand why it isn't working. The pagination links display, but clicking on one brings up Page Not Found.

I implemented the plugin in my category.php template and it works fine there.

And yes, I have re-visited my permalinks settings :)

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Echo out `$paged` to see if in fact has a value. Also on what template are you not successfully using this? And what is the URL you are pointed to when you get the 404 Page error?

Comment: Any testimonial pagination link other than the initial page of testimonials brings up Page Not Found.

Comment: What was the link (URL) that keeps making you end up on the 404? Make doubly sure you have your Permalinks set to a pretty url setting. ie. (/%category%/%postname%/)

Comment: Permalinks are set to /%postname%/. Any pagination link for testimonials causes a Page Not Found error (e.g. http://s13.mynewsitereview.com/testimonials/page/2/, http://s13.mynewsitereview.com/testimonials/page/3/, etc...)

Comment: Does normal pagination work on say your index or archive pages? When in doubt copy over code from the Wordpress default themes, ie. TwentyEleven to see how they did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php

   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

 ?>
```

Make sure you have the above line in your call - as you reference $paged, but don't show it in your question!

Comment: Above your <?php query_posts(array(

Comment: I updated my code and re-uploaded the template file, but the problem still exists...

Comment: Try renaming your page slug different to the custom post type.

Comment: thanks @Foxinni I couldnt get the code widget to fix my tags!